# JMeter: thread switching between variables for preset time periods throughout a test run

Tags: jmeter

I have a script with a once only loop where a thread uses reg expression extractor to get a variable into an array.  After the once only loop, the thread selects a random instance of that variable and then continues with that instance of the variable for the entire test run.

It would be more realistic for the script to do the following:

Jmeter thread uses variable_1 for x seconds, switch to variable_2 for x seconds, switch to variable_3 for x seconds

Variables_1,2,3,x coming from the reg ex array should be selected randomly

x seconds could be 300, 600, 1200 and selected randomly

Is this something that can be accomplished with JMeter controllers/functions or would it require something along the lines of custom beanshell code?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `ForEach Controller` & `Runtime Controller`.

For Each controller is to iterate the variables one by one.

Under Runtime controller, you keep all your samplers to be executed for the duration.

**Test Plan:**

[image]

**For Each Controller config:**

[image]

**Runtime Controller config:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reconsidering your approach as this way you test won't be repeatable. The whole idea of testing is that when you run the test 2 or more times - you should get the same results, elsewise if you discover a product issue you won't be able to reproduce it to ensure that it is fixed.

Coming back to your question: yes it can be done via JMeter Test Elements without having to go into scripting. Take a look at [__chooseRandom()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#chooseRandomsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-0-1-font-sup) function available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project. The easiest way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager]